# How to track Google Analytics events in Google Tag Manager without changing the Goal set in Google analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

For Example i am tracking below event in Google Analytics:

**`Onclick Event`**

```
1. onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'TryForFree', 'TryForFree-clicked', 'TryForFree')"
```

**`On Form Submit Event`**

```
2. onsubmit="ga('send', 'event', 'Get-Started-submitted', 'Get-Started-submitted', 'Get-Started-submitted')"
```

**Here** `eventCategory : TryForFree` , `eventAction : TryForFree-clicked`

My Question is, how can i track same **`Events`** by same **`Name`** in **`Google Tag Manager`** without changing the Goal in **`Google anaytics`**

Answer (score 0):

You can use one or more event category, event action and/or event label as a condition to trigger your goal. If your goal does not match any of the values you are passing in the event, it will not fire.

Answer (score 0):

1. GTM tracks event with the help of triggers. Create a **[triggers](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/trigger-guide-google-tag-manager/)** in GTM
2. Those triggers are identified and initialised by `class` or `id` of that event.

**`For Example`** you have below event, getting tracked by `google analytics` by `hardcoding` it inline.

```
Ex - `<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Login', 'Login-clicked', 'Login-clicked')" href="#">Login</a>`
```

**Now** same event, you have to track with `GTM`, see below:

```
Ex - `<a class="login_event_gtm" href="#">Login</a>`
```

3. Create a class like `login_event_gtm`
4. Make a `trigger`, associate that `class` to the `trigger` and store it in a **[variable](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/variable-guide-google-tag-manager/)**, see below image for reference. [image: Trigger Setup]
5. Finally make a tag and associate the variable to the goal made in GA by the same name.
   like below:
   `eventCategory : Login`
   `eventAction : Login-clicked`
   See below image for reference [image]